# Why did a loving God ask Abraham to kill his own son?

Tags: genesis, abraham, isaac

An agnostic asked me why did a loving God ask Abraham to kill his own son?
I told him it was a test from God.  Did answer him correctly? I did not say anymore

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.stackexchange. This could be the basis for a good question, but is currently too broad and opinion based. To avoid the risk of it being deleted you could ask the position of a particular denomination.

Comment: Hebrews 11:17-19 may shed some light on this (taken from NIV) - _By faith Abraham, when God tested him, offered Isaac as a sacrifice. He who had embraced the promises was about to sacrifice his one and only son, even though God had said to him, "It is through Isaac that your offspring will be reckoned." Abraham reasoned that God could even raise the dead, and so in a manner of speaking he did receive Isaac back from death_.

Comment: I would prefer if you would open the question up by removing the 'loving' part - there were quite a few gods around at the time and Abraham would have paid tribute to them. You are steering the answers.

Comment: To add to what @DickHarfield said, this site deals primarily with what different Christian churches, denominations, and groups believe and teach on various subjects, rather than with what is right or wrong, true or false--which is really a matter of opinion for us humans who don't happen to be omniscient.

Comment: @gideonmarx And how exactly do you know that?

Comment: @curiousdannii You can ask that question on Hermeneutics.

Comment: @gideonmarx No, that would actually be off topic there as it wouldn't be based on any text.

Comment: @DickHarfield you're implying just because **YOU** don't know an answer found in scripture, nobody will know an answer found in scripture, and therefor any answer given will be a matter of opinion. ?

Comment: @curiousdannii I have found quite a bit there already and that sent me looking for more. I don't see how that kind of discussion fits in here. My objection to the question is that it is phrased "loving" - a highly subjective word. And it is an attempt to steer the answers.

Answer (score 2):

God hates human sacrifice.

> Let no one be found among you who sacrifices their son or daughter in
>   the fire, who practices divination or sorcery, interprets omens,
>   engages in witchcraft. *(Deuteronomy 18:10, NIV)*

God was only testing Abraham's faith and obedience.

> [Genesis 22 (NIV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2022)
>
> 1 Some time later **God tested Abraham**. He said to him, “Abraham!” “Here I
>   am,” he replied. 
>   2 Then God said, “Take your son, your only son, whom
>   you love—Isaac—and go to the region of Moriah. Sacrifice him there as
>   a burnt offering on a mountain I will show you.”
>
> 12 “Do not lay a hand on the boy,” he said. “Do not do anything to
>   him. **Now I know that you fear God**, because you have not withheld from
>   me your son, your only son.”

God never really wanted Abraham to sacrifice his son. God has no need of it. Our God doesn't need to eat food or need to sleep. God doesn't even need your money. God wants your faith, obedience and your love.

> Love the LORD your God with all your heart and with all your soul and
>   with all your strength. *(Deuteronomy 6:5, NIV)*

Answer (score 0):

I have thought often about this one, especially as my own father's first male child died after half an hour of life.  The only conclusion I have ever arrived at is that God had a message for Abraham.  Your son is *mine*; but I want him *alive*.  There were religions around at the time in which babies were sacrificed.  God was instructing Abraham.  In short, I connect this with Leviticus 18:21; "And thou shalt not let any of thy seed pass through the fire to Moloch."

Answer (score 0):

It's not just killing. God ask him to offer his only son. This is a picture of offering Jesus Christ after 2000 years. God want to test the faith and obedience of Abraham because God saw that he loved so much is son and Abraham passed the test.